# Change log and version control with visual studio 2010 and tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, build-process

Whats the right method of version controlling my product?
I am using TFS and visual studio 2010.
Currently I am working alone on my project, so its not a team management workflow.
I don't think that I should use an agile workflow because of the reason above.

But I do want to handle builds and know what has changed between each build.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that a one man project is a reason to not go the agile way, but it's up to  you and your decision.
(I define all my projects which I am developing alone with the Scrum Template.)

If you want to know what changed between each build you need to checkin against your work items.

So select a project template which fits for you, define your work in the workitems (task, backlog or user story, wording depends on the project template).

To not checkin without assigning against a workitem you can activate a checkin policy, so TFS will throw a dialog as a reminder.